# Rails - Removing default stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

New to rails. I'm experimenting with adding the Twitter Bootstrap CSS to my project to make my layout look nicer.

However, I think some of the CSS rules from my default Rails app is interfering with the Twitter Bootstrap CSS.

Is there a way where I can remove the existing CSS assets, and just keep using the Bootstrap ones?

Comment: Rails doesn't come with default CSS assets. Be careful not to delete the asset manifests -- `application.css` and `application.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find where the default css files located(assets/stylesheets),remove them.
...of course **don't remove the application.css**

Comment: Do *not* remote the manifest in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`. This is used with the asset pipeline.

Comment: Perfect thanks guys! I left appliactions.css in place, and then removed scaffold.css.scss and now things are great

Answer (score 4):

If you generated a scaffold (which I assume you did), you can remove the default styling by clearing app/assets/stylesheets/scaffold.css.scss. If you delete the scaffold.css.scss file and you generate a new scaffold, the default stylesheet will be added again, this can be alleviated by simply clearing the file of its contents.

Do **not** delete application.css